# Identifying duplicate rows by certain columns and removing

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

I have sql results of 9000k rows and > 10 columns. I need to remove rows as dups that has another row that matches 4 of the columns (not an exact dup row). I've researched and tried various things but nothing gets me all the way there. This is for a one time data conversion and conversion testing for it.

So if row 1 and row 22 have the same values in columns A1 - A22, D1 - D22, H1 - H22 and K1-K22 then it is a dup and I need to remove one of them (with a later date in another column)

If I could do this in sql great but I have limited rights and table access (as it should be!) and cannot perform all sql functions. (e.g. create tables).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something of this nature:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE rowid NOT IN (
SELECT MIN(rowid) 
FROM table
GROUP BY col1, col2
)
```

Replace table with the table you are searching in, col1 and any others with your columns you require to classify something as a duplicate, and rowid with whatever your index column is.